# What is the alternative to find-file-hook when buffer file already exists?

Tags: emacs

I have a series of functions that execute normally when a file is opened or when a particular mode is activated. The `find-file-hook` doesn't get triggered if the file is already open, when I try to open a file that is already open (e.g., in another frame), Emacs correctly switches to that buffer.  However, under that scenario my custom functions do not activate because there is no trigger.  I don't think the standard hooks cover a situation like this one.

What is the alternative, to `find-file-hook` when a buffer file already exists?

Comment: Would you give an example?  Normally hooks apply to the buffer of the file, so the fact that they don't get triggered is the expected behavior.  Do you want code to run in any frame when a particular buffer is switched to there?

Comment: I have married frame-bufs by Al Parker and tabbar by David Ponce:  https://github.com/lawlist/tabbar-lawlist   Opening a file or activating a mode (without visiting a file) switches to a specific frame and then updates the tabbar.  Opening a file also associates a buffer with the frame if frame-bufs-mode is activated.  A `window-configuration-change-hook` leads to problems with my other functions, so I'd prefer not to use that particular hook.  When trying to open a file that is already open, the file opens in the frame with focus instead of activating my custom frame/tabbar functions.

Comment: One function is used to set everything in motion:  `frames-and-tab-groups`, but that function does not get triggered on the rare occasion when I try to visit a file that has already been opened.  When not in frame-bufs-mode, the file being opened is looked at by the function and then it switches to the appropriate frame and then the tabbar is updated accordingly to a tab group containing that newly opened file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd try to use advice for this.  You can tell whatever find-file command you use to make sure your tabbar is set up correctly.  Simple example, since I use ido-find-file:

```
(defun my-find-file ()
  (interactive)
  (call-interactively 'ido-find-file))

(defadvice my-find-file (after do-something)
  (message "doing stuff"))

(ad-activate 'my-find-file)
```

Comment: Thank you very much -- I'll give it a try later this evening.

Comment: @lawlist It looks you weren't such an emacs maven back then :)

Comment: @vfclists -- Oh my ... the years sure are flying right on by ... still not really a maven, but at least I now have a much better understanding of Emacs ...

Answer (score 2):

If this does not happen very often, you could just reopen the file to trigger the `find-file-hook`. To do so, just type `C-x C-v <enter>`.

Comment: Thank you -- I haven't used `find-alternate-file` before -- I'll give that a try.  For development purposes of the new frames / tabbar features, I have created a manual refresh function that is liked to F5.  I've been using the new system for a couple of weeks, and am slowly but surely working out the kinks -- with the help of everyone here in these forums.  :)

Comment: I bind `f5` to a command that reverts the buffer without asking confirmation. But `C-x C-v` is also your friend. Contrast `g` and `C-x C-v` in Dired, for example. Each is useful --- they do different things.